# Bayesian Networks and discretization of variables using K-means clustering

Tags: bayesian, clustering, k-means, discrete-data, bayesian-network

In many approaches to learning Bayesian Networks a solution to tackle continuous variables is to discretize them and apply one of the well established techniques for learning Bayesian Networks containing discrete variables only. Most discretization techiques are univariate in the sense that they act on each variable by itself. This naturally does not consider the interactions between them. Does anyone know if using K-means on all or groups of the variables included in the network and then using the extremes of the resulting clusters as thresholds for the discretization makes sense? If not, which (multivariate) discretization techinques are recommended and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kmeans for quantization makes a lot of sense, as [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_color_quantization.html) example demonstrates. There are some other, more sophisticated, techniques for finding a sparse representation of the data, such that the distortion is minimized. In the context of machine learning it is usually called dictionary learning. In the context of signal processing this is called vector quantization.

There are other options based on information theory where the idea is to choose a quantization scheme such that is consistent with the Bayesian Model in use. A well-known [paper](http://www-robotics.stanford.edu/people/nir/Papers/FrG2.pdf) is "Discretizing Continuous Attributes While Learning Bayesian Networks"